# Is $\widetilde M_{0, n}$ a Mori Dream space?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, geometric-invariant-theory

I'm reading on $\overline M_{0, n}$ and $\widetilde M_{0, n}$. I know that $\overline M_{0, n}$ is a Mori Dream space for $n \leq 6$ and not a Mori Dream space for $n \geq 13$. Is there a similar result about $\widetilde M_{0, n}$ ? I thought there should be some obvious statement of the type "GIT quotients of Mori Dream spaces are themselves Mori Dream spaces" but somehow I'm missing something. I would also like to understand a counterexample to the previous statement.

Comment: What is $\tilde M_{0,n}$?

Comment: Very briefly: there is a $S_n$ action on $\overline M_{0, n}$ (permuting marked points). $\widetilde M_{0, n}$ is then just a GIT quotient with respect to this action.

Comment: Then the answer to the implied question in this case is easy: since the group is finite and the variety is quasiprojective, the GIT quotient is just the usual geometric quotient, so there is a finite surjective map $\bar M_{0,n}\to \tilde M_{0,n}$. Now (normal, $\mathbb{Q}$-factorial) images of MDS are MDS, so $\tilde M_{0, n}$ is a MDS whenever $\bar M_{0, n}$ is.

Comment: (For the statement about images of MDS cf. S. Okawa "On images of Mori dream spaces" Math. Ann. (2016) 364:1315.)

Comment: @PiotrAchinger.  That is not the implication that Alex is asking about.  The moduli space $\overline{M}_{0,n}$ is *not* a Mori dream space for $n\geq 13$.  However, it remains possible that the quotient $\widetilde{M}_{0,n}$ is a Mori dream space.

Comment: That comment was referring to the part "GIT quotients of Mori Dream spaces are themselves Mori Dream spaces" but maybe I misunderstood. I should have written "one of the implied questions"; the other direction seems more difficult. Maybe one could follow the original strategy of Castravet–Tevelev and reduce to the (quotient by $S_{n-3}$ of the) Losev–Manin toric variety blown up at a point in the open torus orbit?

Comment: @PiotrAchinger.  The divisor theory of $\widetilde{M}_{0,n}$ is considerably simpler than the divisor theory of $\overline{M}_{0,n}$.  For instance, the pseudoeffective cone of $\widetilde{M}_{0,n}$ equals the effective cone, and this is simplicial with extremal rays spanned by the $\lfloor (n-2)/2 \rfloor$ irreducible components of the boundary.

Comment: According to Maksym Fedorchuk in https://arxiv.org/abs/1407.7839 (pg 2), this is an open question in general (or was, as of the last update in June 2015).  Obviously this is a busy area lately, so maybe things have changed.